# Display output with out refresh using Django, Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am programming a simple basic calculator

- where I get the input from the user
- taking the input and do the calculation
- and display the output back on the same page

> I have a basic HTML form

```
<form id="html_calc_form" action={%url 'calculation' %} method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
      First Number:<br>
      <input type="number" name="first number" value="0">
      <br>
      Second Number:<br>
      <input type="number" name="second number" value="0">
      <br>
      Operation:<br>
      <select name="operation" multiple>
              <option value="Addition">Addition</option>
              <option value="Subraction">Subraction</option>
              <option value="Muntiplication">Muntiplication</option>
              <option value="Division">Division</option>
        </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" name "submit" value="Submit">
      <output  name="result" ></output>
</form>
```

> Ajax logic to prevent from refreshing the page

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#html_calc_form').submit(function(event){
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            url:'calc/',
            type:'POST',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $('form')[0].reset();
            }
        });

    })
})
```

> In django I have creates a model

```
class Calculation(models.Model):
first_digit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3)
second_digit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3)
CALCULATION_CHOICE = (('+', 'Addition'),
                      ('-', 'Subraction'),
                      ('*', 'Muntiplication'),
                      ('/', 'Division'))
calculate = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CALCULATION_CHOICE)
```

> And finaly my view

```
    def calc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_number = request.POST['first number']
        second_number = request.POST['second number']
        operation = request.POST['operation']

        result = do_calc(operation, first_number, second_number)
                                    # how to pass the result to my tempelate
        value = Calculation.objects.create(
            first_digit=first_number,
            second_digit=second_number,
            calculate=operation
        )
        return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(value))


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'calculation/calculator.html')
```

I want to pass the result to my HTML template and display it in the output field
once I hit the submit button on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

In the `success()` function you should append the result to the innerHTML of the `output` tag and give the output tag an `id` that can be accessed from the JS function

Comment: I know that but my doubt is how to pass my result from my view to my HTML template

Comment: You already send a `JSON` response from the view, all you need to do is to receive your data from your `AJAX` and inject it to the function e.g ` $(#id).innerHTML(response)`

Comment: Ya, but my `JsonResponse` doesn't have the result. My doubt is how to append my result to my `JsonResponse`.

Comment: Try `return JsonResponse({ "result" : value})`